# How to loop data from firestore with custom layout

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have an layout with dummy data

```
body: ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30.0,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 50.0,
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        primary: false,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
        childAspectRatio: 0.8,
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildCard('Cookie mint', '\Rp.3.99',
              'assets/cookiemint.jpg', false, false, context),
          _buildCard('Cookie cream', '\Rp.25.500',
              'assets/cookiecream.jpg', true, false, context),
          _buildCard('Cookie classic', '\Rp.35.000',
              'assets/cookieclassic.jpg', false, true, context),
          _buildCard('Cookie choco', '\Rp.51.500',
              'assets/cookiechoco.jpg', false, false, context),
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

Result

[image]

But when I use real data from firestore, my layout is broken. I use `ListView.builder` to loop this data

```
body: ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30.0,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 50.0,
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        primary: false,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
        childAspectRatio: 0.8,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => _buildCardItem(
              context,
              snapshot.data.documents[index],
              false,
              'assets/burger.jpg',
              false,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

And result is

[image]

I think maybe `ListView.builder` create a new layout inside my layout? I new with Flutter. Is there a way to repeat the data in another way besides using `ListView.builder`? Or still have to use it in what way? Need advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Where you have:

```
children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => _buildCardItem(
              context,
              snapshot.data.documents[index],
              false,
              'assets/burger.jpg',
              false,
            ),
          )
        ]
```

You have to place a list of widgets. On your attempt, you have put a listView which is a single widget that represents a list of scrollable itens. They are different.

Your itens are based on the `snapshot.data.documents` list. You can use it with a .map function to create another widget list based on that:

```
children: snapshot.data.documents.map(
(item) => _buildCardItem(
              context,
              item,
              false,
              'assets/burger.jpg',
              false,
            )

).toList(),
```

Comment: Hi @Naslausky Thanks for this advice. I tried your code and get error https://ibb.co/jHrhRY7

Comment: My _buildCardItem widget called and get data use `DocumentSnapshot`. When your code using map and send `item` as parameter, should I changet code to get this param?

Comment: @Bertho Joris I don't know how _buildCardItem() is implemented, but if you are using map you should use a function that gets a item from documents and builds a Widget of it. If you want, you can stop using map and instead use a function that creates the whole array.

Comment: My code like `Widget _buildCardItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot,
      bool isFavorite, String imgPath, bool added) {` You can see `second` parameter is `DocumentSnapshot`. It is wrong?

Comment: I Forgot to add ```toList()``` in the end of the map function. I edited my answer. Give it a try now.

Comment: Is fine using my code `Widget _buildCardItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, bool isFavorite, String imgPath, bool added)` Second parameter is still same or must be change?

Comment: You can keep buildCardItem the same way it is. Just don't forget to add the "toList()" at the end. You should be able to use the same builder function you were using ou ListView.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the outer most `ListView` you have 3 scrollable widgets nested together this doesn't seem necessary to me and a lot of people have been having issues with `ListView` firestore and `StreamBuilder` if its not adding anything I'd try removing it.

```
snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) => document.data['//Youlabels']);
```

Comment: I just don't know how to use `children: snapshot.data.documents.map` to iterate one by one. I get most sample code using `ListView.builder`. Thats why I ask. New to try flutter

Comment: Based on your code, I use new widget to pass the data. My widget with parameter like `_buildCardItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, bool isFavorite, String imgPath, bool added)`. It is fine or must be change to pass data from `snapshot.data.documents.map` ??

Comment: can I see your code starting from your ```StreamBuilder``` i know thats most of it probably.

Comment: glad you fixed it

Comment: Thanks @wcyankees424

Answer (score 0):

After browsing, I fixed with my sample code

```
children: snapshot.data.documents.map<Widget>((document) {
  return ListTile(
    title: Text(document['item_name']),
    subtitle: Text(document['item_price']),
  );
}).toList(),
```